# ¿Cómo mostrar html extraído desde una base de datos con ejs?

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, ejs

Estoy desarrollando un blog y me encontré con un problema. Estoy usando de base de datos mongodb ,mi servidor esta hecho en nodejs con express. Tengo creado modelos para los artículos del blog. Estos modelos tienen de propiedades la imagen de artículo,el titulo,descripción,descripción breve, y likes.

Estos artículos se muestran renderizando este archivo ejs:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="article">
<img src="<%=image%>">
<h2 class="title"><%=title%></h2>
<p class="description"><%=description%></p>
<p><%=likes%></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tengo un artículo en la base de datos en el que la propiedad description contiene html

```
description:"<h1>Mi descripción</h1>"
```

Pero el contenido se muestra de esta manera.
[Blog En desarrollo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly56p.jpg)

Lo que deseo es que se muestre como html y no como un texto como en la imagen anterior.En la cual se ven las tags 
Quiero saber como puedo resolver esto.Me es bastante difícil explicar esto. Por favor preguntenme si tienen alguna duda. Gracias!

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto y no se por donde empezar" no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre muy amplia y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante 
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). 
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas! Nos dices "cuando escribo el código para que ejs...", ¿cuál es ese código? Edita e incluye la parte relevante

Comment: Gracias por los consejos hermano. Voy a intentar hacer la mejor descripción posible. Soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Me parece que lo que buscas es insertar el valor de tu variable como `html` **no escapado** (*unescaped*). Para ello prueba usando: `<%- description %>`. (Reemplaza el `tag` actual `<%=` por `<%-`). Más información en la [documentación](https://ejs.co/#docs). Saludos

Comment: Gracias hermano me sirvió usar el <%- en lugar de <%=. Ya está funcionando todo correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Haz un script que convierta primero el string que deseas insertar

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const htmlString = "<h1>Mi descripción</h1>";
const description = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
```

o en una sola linea `new DOMParser().parseFromString("<h1>Mi descripción</h1>", "text/html");`

No lo he probado directamente con EJS pero al menos en Js puro funciona, espero te ayude de algo.

Comment: Si bien esta solución podría funcionar, no es lo que busca el OP, ya que claramente se desea hacer el render desde el lado del servidor, el código que propones es para el lado cliente, donde la variable `description` no está disponible. Saludos